# java - fastest way to iterate through List<Map> and compare contents of Map to known data

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, optimization

I have a small java class that will be run on a cloud application server, so it needs to execute as fast as possible.

What I need to do is iterate over a `List<Map>`, get the contents of the current `Map` and then do some logic on it. The `Map` contains strings and doubles.

This is my current implementation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

  Map data = result.get(i);
  double priceToCheck = Double.parseDouble(data.get("value").toString());
  String criteria = data.get("criteria").toString();
  String coin = data.get("coin").toString();


  if (coin.equals("BTC")) {
    if (criteria.equals("above")) {
      if (BTC > priceToCheck) {
        // create notficaition
        sendNotification = true;

      }
    } else {
      if (BTC < priceToCheck) {
        // create notification
        sendNotification = true;
      }
    }
  } else if (coin.equals("BCH")) {
    if (criteria.equals("above")) {
      if (BCH > priceToCheck) {
        // create notficaition
        sendNotification = true;
      }
    } else {
      if (BCH < priceToCheck) {
        // create notification
        sendNotification = true;
      }
    }
  } else if (coin.equals("ETH")) {
    if (criteria.equals("above")) {
      if (ETH > priceToCheck) {
        // create notficaition
        sendNotification = true;
      }
    } else {
      if (ETH < priceToCheck) {
        // create notification
        sendNotification = true;
      }
    }
  } else if (coin.equals("ETC")) {
    if (criteria.equals("above")) {
      if (ETC > priceToCheck) {
        // create notficaition
        sendNotification = true;
      }
    } else {
      if (ETC < priceToCheck) {
        // create notification
        sendNotification = true;
      }
    }
  } else if (coin.equals("LTC")) {
    if (criteria.equals("above")) {
      if (LTC > priceToCheck) {
        // create notficaition
        sendNotification = true;
      }
    } else {
      if (LTC < priceToCheck) {
        // create notification
        sendNotification = true;
      }
    }
  } else if (coin.equals("XRP")) {
    if (criteria.equals("above")) {
      if (XRP > priceToCheck) {
        // create notficaition
        sendNotification = true;
      }
    } else {
      if (XRP < priceToCheck) {
        // create notification
        sendNotification = true;
      }
    }

  }
```

Where `result` is a `List<Map>`, `"BTC"` is a string and `BTC` is a double

As you can see the highest level if statements checks the string `coin`, there are six possible values. Once the `coin` is found I determine the value of `criteria`, and then do a comparison of doubles depending on the value of `criteria`

I feel as though this is a very cumbersome way of accomplishing this task, it works but its relatively slow. I can't think of a way to speed it up without directly accessing every `Map` element and manually checking the contents.

Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Create a List of Coin where each Coin has a name and value.  then the inner set of if blocks can collapse into a loop over the list of coins.  also, it seems like you only ever set one value, "sendNotification".  the first time you find this to be true, you can break out of all the loops.

Comment: @jtahlborn thanks for that. I can't break out of the loop because there may be multiple objects in the 'result' List<Map> that requires an associated notification, so break would only allow me the find the first. Also coin is string value only

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a List of a Map? Will you be dealing with multiple Maps that may contain the same key? for instance the name of the coin? IMHO it looks like you just want a List of POJO's that you want to populate with a map.

Comment: @shinjw a list of Map is what is returned from the cloud server when I access it's database using it's API

Answer (score 2):

> I have a small java class that will be run on a cloud application server, so it needs to execute as fast as possible.

First of all, there there are some assumptions in there that is doubtful.

1. Yes, it is nice for your code to run as fast as possible, but in most cases it is not necessary.   And in particular, the fact that you running on a cloud server does not necessarily make it essential.
2. You assume your application is not running fast enough.  (Have you benchmarked it?)
3. You assume that this part of the code is (or will be) responsible for the code being too slow.  (Have you implemented it?  Have you profiled it?)

And this:

> I feel as though this is a very cumbersome way of accomplishing this task, it works but its relatively slow.

Cumbersome and slow are not the same.  Often cumbersome verbose / clunky is *faster* than concise / elegant.

---

So now to the *potential* performance issues with your code.  (Bearing in mind that this could all be irrelevant of your assumptions are incorrect!)

1. If the fields are / can be known at compile time, is better to use a custom class than a `Map`.  The `Map::get` method will be orders of magnitude slower than a getter on a custom class, and a Map will typically use an order of magnitude more memory.

   A custom class will also allow you to use primitive types, etcetera instead of shoehorning the values into `String`.  Avoiding that will have performance benefits too.
2. This is slow:

   ```
   double priceToCheck = Double.parseDouble(data.get("value").toString());
   ```

   You appear to be taking a `double` (or a `Double`)`, converting it to a string and then converting it back to a`double`.  Conversions between numbers and decimal strings are relatively expensive.
3. If the values of `coin` and `criteria` are known at compile time, consider using an `enum` or `boolean` rather than a String.  Comparison will be faster, and you will be able to use a `switch` statement ... or a simple `if` in the boolean case.

In fact, the iteration through the list is one aspect where this not a lot of opportunity to optimize.

Comment: Thanks for this. The cloud server the code will run on has a limit of 5 seconds for execution. Unfortunately the fields are unknown at compile time and are read in from a database on the cloud server each time the code executes. This requires the use of the Map, and all elements of the map are objects, is there a better way to convert from object to double?

Comment: 0)  So ... the *real* reason you need to optimize is the 5 second time limit.  (Nothing to do with "cloud" really.  There could be a time limit on any server!)  1)  If really you have to use a `Map`, there is little scope for optimization.  Look at the way you are reading from the database to see if you can use a custom class.  I expect that there is. 2) What is the real type of the object?

Comment: Yes I will check if I can implement a custom class instead. The API I use returns java.lang.Object for each element in the map. On the server side though "value" is a double

Comment: Find out what the real type is on the client side.  It will NOT be `java.lang.Object`.  I can guarantee that.

Comment: On the client side (swift iOS app) "value" is a double

Comment: @stephenC is providing some valuable feedback. If you are consuming an API and the response returns [{coin: 'BTC', value: 1.23, criteria: 'above'}], you can deserialize that to a custom class.

Comment: @MitchellD - You didn't actually answer my question.  However, my *guess* is that it is actually a `java.lang.Double`. If that is the case, then cast it to a `Double` and use `Double::doubleValue`

Comment: @StephenC sorry, to clarify, the client side app is written in Swift, not Java

Comment: @shinjw yes thank you I am taking on board Stephen's suggestion as we speak and implementing a custom class

Answer (score 0):

There is one optimization that really stands out here. Your original code snippit will iterate through your entire list to adjust your `sendNotification` boolean.

If setting `sendNotification` all you need to do, you can strategically place `break` in each of your conditional. This will short-circuit the loop after the desired behavior. In the worst case scenario you would end up iterating through your entire list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {


  if (coin.equals("BTC")) {
    if (criteria.equals("above")) {
      if (BTC > priceToCheck) {
        // create notficaition
        sendNotification = true;
        break; // exits the loop

      }
    } else {
      if (BTC < priceToCheck) {
        // create notification
        sendNotification = true;
        break;
      }
   }
  } else if (coin.equals("BCH")) {
    if (criteria.equals("above")) {
      if (BCH > priceToCheck) {
        // create notficaition
        sendNotification = true;
        break;
      }
```